# How to call component method inside sibling component without creating a service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular project in which I have 3 components: container, sidenav, main-content.

**container.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
  <app-main-content></app-main-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**sidenav.component.ts**

```
is_open = false;

toggleSidenav() {
  this.is_open = !this.is_open;
}
```

I need to retrieve the is_open value from the main-content component.

My idea was to create a template reference from **app-sidenav** (let's say #sidenav) and use its property inside **main-content.component.html** (sidenav.is_open) but how do I achieve this?

I know I can create a service for that but since it's only for one property (is_open), I don't want to create a single service for this. Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: So you want to open/close your sidenav from within `app-main-content`, correct?

Comment: No, I only need the boolean value to add a specific class to a div inside app-main-content if it's true.

Comment: if you add `#sidenav` to the element, and then you add an html element below your main-content with `{{ sidenav?.is_open }}` do you get a boolean, or do you get undefined?

Comment: I get a boolean but I want to use that boolean in the <app-main-content> which is a separate component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate between two Angular components there are multiple strategies such as:

- @Output() and @Input()
- Service with Observables
- Setters and Getters
- Third party state management libraries (NgRx)
- Component Injection

Since you are not interested in the services (And I do not see in your question what is the constraint) you can simlply use @Input() and @Output which are [available here in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) to help you understand how to facilitate the communication between parent and child components in Angular.

Comment: My "constraint" about using a service is that I would need to create a service which would only contain a boolean property. But since I'm still a beginner, would you recommend me to still use a service for that?

Comment: As I mentioned to you above, there are multiple strategies for components communication. Since you have one property your way to go is Property binding. Read here: https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works. Thanks to mark the response as resolved if it guides you to the right way